# Integrating an infinite series with no exponent

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

So I saw a Khan Academy video which showed how you could find upper and lower bounds when integrating an infinite series to give you a decent idea of what it equates to. So an example is:

$$
s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/n^2) 
$$
$$
s_5=\sum_{n=1}^5 (1/n^2)=1.4636
$$
$$
\int_6^\infty (1/n^2)dn=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_6^b(1/n^2)dx
$$
$$
=\lim_{b\to\infty}[-n^{-1}]_b^6
$$
$$
=\lim_{b\to\infty}({-1/b})+(1/6)=1/6
$$
That is the lower bound.
$$
\int_5^\infty(1/n^2)dx=1/5
$$
That is the upper bound.
$$
1.4636+1/6\leq s \geq 1.4636+1/5
$$
$$
1.63\leq s \geq 1.664
$$
My question is about integrating an infinite series without an exponent (or with an exponent of one). More specifically,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-\log n-xi\log n)
$$
How would you integrate this? i in this examples is sqrt(-1) and x is any real number. Where you would normally add 1 to the exponent and divide by -1, do you do exactly the same? Also do you do this to both expressions
$$-\log n$$ and $$-xi\log n$$? I understand these questions may be rather basic, but I haven't studied integration yet and learning it on the internet is more difficult than you'd think- there are gaps in my knowledge which I do not know exist because I am not going by a curriculum.

Thank you for all help,
Luke

Comment: i did not understand the question. can you give an example of an infinite series you would like to integrate?

Comment: @gt6989b there's one in the question - $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (- \log n - xi \log n)$.

Comment: $i = \sqrt{-1}$ so this is a complex series? $x$ is any real number?

Comment: @gt6989b yes i is sqrt(-1) and x is any real number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Different functions satisfy different rules for integration. While (most) powers of $n$ can be integrated using the rule $\int n^k = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}  +C$, the specific form of the integral depends on the function. In this case, the integral of the natural log is given by $$\int \log n = n \log n - n + C$$so the integral you are looking for is $$\int_{k}^\infty (-\log n - xi \log n) dn = (-1-xi) \int_{k}^\infty \log n dn  =  (-1-xi)(n \log n - n) \Big]_{n=k}^\infty$$
Where the second expression follows because constant multiples can be "extracted" from integrals. I would recommend studying some calculus on your own, to learn about how we can use integrals, the theory behind them, as well as techniques to calculate them.